# How should I integrate my account database with a support ticketing system?

Tags: architecture, ticket-system

Background: A B2C company where a customer orders a product, receives delivery, uses the product to send information to the company for analysis, and gets back a response. The customer needs to be able to contact the company for support at any of these stages.

I am designing a support system that will have users submitting tickets from web and in-app forms (possibly also phone) and the agents will handle the tickets using a commercial ticketing system (Zendesk, Freshdesk, Helpspot, or similar).
Many of the submissions will be from people who are existing users in my system and as such I have data about their account and activity that would be helpful to the support agent handling the ticket.  I want that when a support agent opens a ticket, they will have all the information available - both the info the customer submitted from the form and any info we have about that user/account/issue in our DB.  Moreover, since the reality of an issue can change between ticket creation and the agent viewing it (an order was in place A and now is in place B), we need a way for the ticket to show the *current* info.

What is a suggested architecture for doing this?

---

The two ideas I've got so far:

1. **Server-driven.**

- For ticket creation: The front-ends (web, mobile, phone), go to my server, the server uses the account ID to collect any additional info and then makes the ticket create call to the ticketing system with all the info.
- For system info updates:  When the information about the account (order status or similar) updates in my server, push the update to the CS ticketing system.

2. **Ticketing system driven.**

- For ticket creation: The front-ends make the call directly to the ticketing system and the ticketing system has an "on-create" trigger that calls my server to get any additional information and then updates the ticket.
- For system info updates:  Have the ticketing system call the server for updated info about the account / user / order either automatically on ticket open or with an agent-triggered request.

Answer (score 0):

Excepted if your server is a CRM, don't impact it with new roles, which belong to the newly added system. Keep the ticket creation in the ticketting tool, letting it find the additional information it needs (perhaps tomorrow more info, from other systems?)

So, as to me, second solution is better. You now have to define how to maintain the fresh info on the ticketting system. Your idea looks fine (the ticketting is the one which requests).

You will then have no coupling from your server to the ticketting system, and you can change or enhance the way this ticketting system get info, with rather low impact.